# Order topology on $\Bbb Q^+$ as a Z-module

Tags: general-topology, modules, topological-groups, topological-rings

Consider the multiplicative group of strictly positive rationals, denoted $\Bbb Q^+$. This can be viewed as a $\Bbb Z$-module, with the primes serving as a basis.

If we place the order topology on $\Bbb Q^+$, this turns it into a topological $\Bbb Z$-module.

**Main question:** Does this naturally induce a topology on the dual module $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Q^+, \Bbb Z)$?

Secondary question: Does this naturally induce a topology on $\Bbb Z$, making it a topological ring?

Comment: How is $\Bbb{Q}^+$ a $\Bbb{Z}$-module, how do you define $\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Q}^+\ni(-1)\cdot 1$ as an element of $\Bbb{Q}^+$?

Comment: @sqtrat: $m \cdot r = r^m$.

Comment: First, represent each rational as $2^a_2 \cdot 3^a_3 \cdot 5^a_5 ...$. Then the tuple (a_2, a_3, a_5, ...) can be thought of an element in a Z-module, with addition equating to multiplication on the rationals and scalar multiplication equating to exponentiation.

Comment: Very interesting, I haven't seen this!

Comment: I don't understand your first question.  How would this induce a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: My question is: is there some standard way in which a topological R-module induces a topology on R?

Comment: How about the coarsest topology on $R$ such that the map $R\times M \rightarrow M$ is continuous? I'm not sure if this will however guarantee that the addition and multiplication in $R$ is continuous, though one can still look at the coarsest topology on $R$ such that these are continuous as well.

Comment: The preimage of a M will just be generated by divisors of the gcd of the exponents, always paired with negatives. When we project onto the integers we'll get the divisor topology with some extra baggage (1 and $\pm$'s everywhere). I don't think this is affected by making the ring operations continuous (What's Z normally as a topological ring?)

Comment: My main question is whether or not a topology is induced on the dual module, so maybe I should edit to make clear...

Comment: So there's an isomorphism to the group of infinitely many copies of the integers in which all but finitely many are 0. I think the dual group should just be the same withhout the finite condition, i.e. a linear map over these indices. The map given by the module still is just a index-wise multiplication so we still produce the same divisor topology when we project onto the integers.

Comment: Jason Carr - so as you mentioned, the dual module to Q^+ is essentially the set of integer sequences in which infinitely many numbers can be zero. The set of rationals injects into this space, so that you can think of this space as having "extra" rationals with infinite prime factorizations. The reason I got hung up is I wasn't sure if the idea of an "order topology" would carry over to that setting, but the stuff you're writing about divisor topologies looks interesting - would love to understand better! if you'd be willing to elaborate as an answer and show I'll award the question to you.